# VBA - check if xml node exists - if not use other one

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I want to copy data from xml file to excel workbook
Every xml has got tag "Client name" but some of them also have got tag "Billing client name"
I want to achieve this with my code
If in xml tag "Billing client name" exists use it and ignore tag "Client name"
if in xml there is no tag "Billing client name" use data from tag "Client name"
My current code only paste data from tag "Client name"

My code:

```vb
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox LR
For x = 2 To LR

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.Async = False
    xmlDoc.Load ("\\path\" & Range("A" & x) & ".xml")

    Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BILL_TO_CLIENTCODE")
    Set nodeXML2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CLIENTCODE")

    If nodeXML Is Nothing Then

        Range("B" & x).Value = nodeXML(i).Text

    Else

        Range("B" & x).Value = nodeXML2(i).Text

    End If

Next x
```

If I change last lines of code to:

```vb
If nodeXML Is Nothing Then
    Range("B" & x).Value = nodeXML2(i).Text
Else
    Range("B" & x).Value = nodeXML(i).Text
End If
```

I only get value from tag "Billing client name" and no value if this tag doesn't exists

sample xml

```
<InvoiceData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/InvoiceData.xsd">
   <INVOICE_HEADER>
        <BILL_TO_CLIENTCODE/>
        <CLIENTCODE>61138259</CLIENTCODE>
```

second one has got value in tag Bill to clientcode and in clientcode but Bill to clientcode should be primary.

Comment: Is this your entire code? What is the `i` variable and when does this change? You should really consider ensuring that `Option Explicit` is at the top of your module.

Comment: Then you have `If nodeXML Is Nothing` but then you're still attempting to use `nodeXML(i).Text` - even when you've determined it to be `Nothing`.

Comment: Also consider using meaningful names for things. Like `xmlBillToClientCode` and `xmlClientCode` are more meaningful than `nodeXML` and `nodeXML2` in context.

Comment: As I can see there is no "i" variable in my code

Comment: There is an `i` variable - it's undeclared inside of your `nodeXML(i)`. Which would have been caught with `Option Explicit` being at the top of your module. You're using it as your index number of your `nodeXML` collection.

Comment: I'm working to the last row - there is LR variable

Answer (score 2):

`xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName` always return a collection, but that collection may be empty if there are no matches, so you need to test for (eg)

```
 If nodeXML.Length > 0 Then
```

and not check whether `nodeXML` is Nothing

So something like this should work (untested):

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook, xmlDoc As Object
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht = mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    For x = 2 To sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        xmlDoc.Async = False
        xmlDoc.Load ("\\path\" & Range("A" & x) & ".xml")

        sht.Range("B" & x).Value = PreferredValue(xmlDoc, _
                  Array("BILL_TO_CLIENTCODE", "CLIENTCODE"))

    Next x
End Sub

Function PreferredValue(doc As Object, arrTags)
    Dim t, col, rv
    For Each t In arrTags
        Set col = doc.getElementsByTagName(t)
        If col.Length > 0 Then
            rv = col(0).Text
            If Len(rv) > 0 Then Exit For '<<<< EDIT
        End If
    Next t
    PreferredValue = rv
End Function
```

Comment: This solution only give me data for tag "Clientcode" - ignores "Bill to client code"

Comment: Thank You - but it only gives me data from "BILL_TO_CLIENTCODE"  tag and ignores tag "ClienCode"

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample XML ?  Doesn't need all the content, but enough to test with.

Comment: 1) Fine answer +1:-) 2.) Closer to the original coding the question could be solved also via  `Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("BILL_TO_CLIENTCODE")` and `Set nodeXML2 = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("CLIENTCODE")` (assuming these tags one level under the document element, otherwise using a double slash `//` before the nodename) and the negative following check `If Not nodeXML Is Nothing Then` 3.) If early binding, I'd prefer the latest MSXML2 version 6.0 via `CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` instead of `Microsoft.XMLDOM`.

Comment: OP apparently wants to ignore empty node texts, not only not existing node names (so Point 2 in above comment would have to be changed, too).

Comment: I have added sample xml file

Comment: " If in xml tag 'Billing client name' exists" is different from " If in xml tag 'Billing client name' exists **and has a value**"  See my edit above.